# Reference multiple 'template' sheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a VBA code (below) which runs through my first sheet (Invoices) and creates individual sheets based on the Invoice Number. At the moment it uses a template, from sheet 'Template'.

I'd like to be able to:

Firstly - choose whether to reference 'Template' or 'Hire Template' (depending on if the invoice is a standard or a hire invoice) based on a cell value in my Invoices sheet (perhaps a column entitled 'Hire' where the value is either y or n).

Secondly - rather than run this in one full go, have it create a new sheet only when a new row is filled in the Invoices sheet (perhaps this is when the Invoice Number column is given a value in the next blank row).

As I'm sure you can tell my current code is compiled from a number of sources, mostly from Google searches, and then tweaked to suit my needs. As such it probably isn't the most elegant or concise way of doing things. I'd appreciate any guidance on how to improve my code to better suit my needs!

The other thing it does is create some hyperlinked cells for ease of navigation around the Workbook (which can be up to 100+ sheets), but I'm happy with how they work in this example.

Also the Column and Row resizing is a bit of a bodge to get things tidy. Is there a neater way of referencing this from the Template (or Hire Template) sheets accordingly?

Please let me know if there's anything I can be clearer on or any further information I can provide to help you to help me!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Rhys

```
Sub AddNamedSheets()
Dim srcName, dstName As Range
Dim invoicesSheet As Worksheet
Dim templateSheet As Worksheet
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Dim myBook As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim namesColumn


'Define your workbook - here set as the active workbook
Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook

'Define your worksheets - The sheets are named "Invoices" and "Template" respectively
Set invoicesSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Invoices")
Set templateSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Template")

'Define which column in your master tab the list is - here it's B i.e. column 2
namesColumn = 2

'Find the last row of the sheets list
lastRow = invoicesSheet.Cells(invoicesSheet.Rows.Count, namesColumn).End(xlUp).Row


'Cycle through the list - Assuming the list starts in column "A" from the 2nd row
For i = 2 To lastRow

'Create Worksheets and Copy Row
  Set srcName = Sheets("Invoices").Range("A" & i)
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
     ActiveSheet.Name = srcName
       srcName.Range("A" & 1).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("J3")
'Create Hyperlink to new sheet
         srcName.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=srcName, _
             Address:="", SubAddress:=srcName & "!J3", _
             TextToDisplay:=srcName.Value
'Create HyperLink back to Main sheet
  Set dstName = ActiveSheet.Range("J3")
         dstName.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=dstName, _
             Address:="", SubAddress:="'Invoices'!A1", _
             TextToDisplay:=dstName.Value
'Copy data from template
Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:J46").Copy _
    Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

Rows("1").RowHeight = 110
Rows("2").RowHeight = 30
Rows("3:6").RowHeight = 21
Rows("7:34").RowHeight = 20
Rows("35:44").RowHeight = 21
Rows("45:46").RowHeight = 16

Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 15
Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 17.5
Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 20
Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 15



  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of adding a blank sheet and then formatting it to look like the template, why not just copy the template?

Comment: That's a good question, and I'm sure there was a reason when I originally put this together a year or so ago. Something to do with the renaming the sheet perhaps? I don't remember! 

Could you make a suggestion on how to handle that within the above code? Happy to provide an example sheet if that would be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but something like:

```
Sub AddNamedSheets()

    Dim srcName, dstName As Range
    Dim invoicesSheet As Worksheet
    Dim templateSheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myBook As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim namesColumn

    Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook

    Set invoicesSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Invoices")

    'Define which column in your master tab the list is - here it's B i.e. column 2
    namesColumn = 2

    'Find the last row of the sheets list
    lastRow = invoicesSheet.Cells(invoicesSheet.Rows.Count, namesColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    'Cycle through the list - Assuming the list starts in column "A" from the 2nd row
    For i = 2 To lastRow

        'which template to copy? keys off ColJ here for example
        If LCase(invoicesSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value) = "y" Then
            Set templateSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Hire Template")
        Else
            Set templateSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Template")
        End If

        'copy the template and rename it
        templateSheet.Copy after:=myBook.Worksheets(myBook.Worksheets.Count)
        Set NewSheet = myBook.Worksheets(myBook.Worksheets.Count)
        NewSheet.Name = srcName.Value

        Set srcName = invoicesSheet.Range("A" & i)
        srcName.Copy Destination:=NewSheet.Range("J3")
        Set dstName = NewSheet.Range("J3")

        'Create Hyperlink to new sheet
        srcName.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=srcName, _
            Address:="", SubAddress:=srcName & "!J3", _
            TextToDisplay:=srcName.Value

        'Create HyperLink back to Main sheet
        dstName.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=dstName, _
            Address:="", SubAddress:="'Invoices'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=dstName.Value

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I've given this a try and it throws up an error at 'NewSheet.Name = srcName.Value', I think because srcName isn't defined yet?


I've uploaded an example version of my spreadsheet - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GdACHM0sSb7XFmSpeWQAe6RQP2Afo1Hf


I'd be really grateful if you had the time to take a look. My original code is Module1 and your code above is Module2 (it keys off ColD so have updated to suit).


Your code looks great though, exactly the advice I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try moving the `Set srcName = ...` line up?

Comment: Ah I did and it didn't work, but have just tried it again and it all works great! Thanks so much for your help and advice!

Comment: I don't suppose you have any ingenious solution to the second part of my question?

Rather than run this in one full go, have it create a new sheet only when a new row is filled in the Invoices sheet (perhaps this is when the Invoice Number column is given a value in the next blank row).

Comment: You can use an event handler to respond to data entries, but I would go with a button which creates a sheet for the row(s) which is/are currently selected

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice. I've done just that - a button which creates a sheet for the selected row. Thanks again for all your help!